# Meteor.js loginWithGoogle() isn't working while using with React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, meteor, react-native-meteor

I'm working on the ReactNative app, and there is need for Google OAuth SignIn using Meteor. While the login configuration works on Meteor side, it's not recognized as function when called from RN App.

Code I've written is as follows:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Meteor, { Accounts, connectMeteor, loginWithGoogle } from 'react-native-meteor';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: null
    };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    const url = "ws://localhost:3000/websocket"

    Meteor.connect(url);
    console.log(this.state.user);
  }
  
  getMeteorData() {
    return {
      user: Meteor.user()
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    if (!this.state.user) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this._signIn()}}>
            <Text>Sign In</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    }
    
    if (this.state.user) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold', marginBottom: 20}}>
            Welcome {this.state.user.name}
          </Text>
          <Text>
            Your email is: {this.state.user.email}
          </Text>

          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this._signOut(); }}>
            <View style={{marginTop: 50}}>
              <Text>Log out</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
  
  _signIn() {
    Meteor.loginWithGoogle({
      requestPermissions: ['email']
    }, function (error) {
        if (error) {
          console.log("Error: ", error);
        } else {
          console.log(Meteor.user());
        }
      }
    );
  }
  
  _signOut() {
    Meteor.logout();
  }
  
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
});

export default App;
```

But when the 'Sign In' button is pressed, the following error comes up:

```
_reactNativeMeteor2.default.loginWithGoogle is not a function
```

Any help/suggestions ?

Comment: The `Meteor` object from `react-native-meteor` implements only a subset of the functionality offered by the browser version. Moreover, the Google login functionality is different from the web one, as the app cannot simply "redirect" to the google oAuth page in the same view and the same API of a web page (which is what the browser Meteor version does). I assume that you will need to research existing react-native oAuth options and implement the missing  functionality yourself.

Comment: @MasterAM after doing some researches, I came to find out (at least what I think it is) that `ddp-client` could be used to make connection with `Meteor` from `React App` to be able to use function `loginWithGoogle`.

Is it done using `ddp-client` or not?
If it is, then which would you recommend for **React Native**?

Comment: You could call the methods defined by Meteor's `accounts-google` package, but you would have to wire the keys (client id, user token) yourself to and from the server, probably using a react-native package for the interaction with Google's servers.